# Ext4: I/O errors on a clean external drive

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

So I've an external Seagate hard disk that I used to mount on my Mac through Paragon ExtFS.

For some unknown reason it stopped to mount on my Mac due to I/O errors - I may have removed the drive without dismounting.

Okay. I tried to mount this drive on the Ubuntu machine I use on my work, and it mounted. I found some bizarre permission errors here and there, but most of them were resolved after executing the `fsck` and `chown`/`chgrp` commands.

I now have only two directories with I/O issues, although `fsck` says my drive is clean. Although I can list their contents with `ls`/`find` commands, I can't `stat` anything inside them. Using `debugfs` on those "hidden" files I was able to see that they've `uid=501` and `gid=20`.

My question: is there any way/tool to fix these files permissions? Using `fsck` wasn't enough to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [debugfs(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) but if you care for your data you'll better use that on some disk image, not on the partition itself.